# Unable to join my own Minecraft server while others can

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I had a Minecraft server on my main PC, and decided to move it to my laptop. When I started it, my friends could join with my public IP address, but I can't join with the IPv4 IP nor the public IP. I tried disabling Windows Defender on both devices, but I still couldn't join.
The server is connected to the same router I'm using on my main PC, so I'm wondering why I can't join.
I also tried allowing port 25565 in Windows Defender, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you point your IP forwarding to your laptop?

Comment: Yup I did Im sure I did it right since when I go to portchecker.co it says port open when the servers running

Comment: What IP are you using to connect (should be 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x)? Run `ipconfig` on your server computer and client computer and look for an address like the one I posted. Use the address on your server computer to connect on your client. Also, what router are you using? | It is very unlikely for that IP to be 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.1 (those are usually reserved for the router/modem itself)

Comment: I am using pldt fibr f670L and  i used the ip in ipconfig still doesnt work

Comment: Your router (as configured by your ISP) is likely preventing connection via LAN, i.e., you won't be able to connect to any other device connected to that router—your laptop in this case. There's not much you can do about it unless you contact your ISP and ask them to enable this functionality (or how to enable it).

Comment: enable what function exactly?

Comment: @AppleFrenzy The "allow connecting to other computers via LAN" functionality (it's a setting in your router that has been pre-configured by your ISP). You might need to discuss this in forums with people who share the same ISP (as there are methods that are too complicated to discuss or troubleshoot here), or just contact your ISP about it and tell them you can't connect to other computers via LAN.

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, what Minecraft version?

Comment: Windows 11 and a fabric server modpack 1.18.2